# How to modify and save a 16-bit depth RGBA image with icc color profile in python?

Tags: python, image, opencv, python-imaging-library, color-profile

I am searching for a long time on net. But found nothing useful. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.
I have some **16-bit depth per channel RGBA with icc color profile png** images, and want to **remove their Alpha channel and save it with original icc profile**. I tried python-opencv and PIL.Image. Opencv could save 16-bit RGBA image but without icc profile, PIL.Image could save image with icc profile but it doesn't support 16-bit RGBA image.
Am I using these two modules wrong? Or is there any other modules could handle this?

**Here`s my code(simplified):**

opencv part:

```
src_image = cv2.imdecode(np.fromfile(file_path, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

detect bit depth
if src_image.dtype == "uint8":
    depth_value = 255
if src_image.dtype == "uint16":
    depth_value = 65535

# if alpha channel is full white, then remove alpha channel
b, g, r, a = cv2.split(src_image)
if np.all(a == depth_value):
    merged = cv2.merge([b,g,r])
    cv2.imwrite(out_path,merged,[cv2.IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION,png_comp])
else:
    pass
```

PIL.Image part:

```
image = Image.open(image_path)
image.load()

r, g, b, a = image.split()
print(r.mode) #it prints "L"
image = Image.merge('BGR;16',(b,g,r)) #ValueError: wrong number of bands

image.save(out_path,bits = 'BGR;16',icc_profile=image.info.get('icc_profile')) #I only found "BGR;16" and no "RGB;16"
```

And modes in PIL.Image module [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#modes) attched below:

> **Modes**
>
> The mode of an image is a string which defines the type and depth of a pixel in the image. Each pixel uses the full range of the bit depth. So a 1-bit pixel has a range of 0-1, an 8-bit pixel has a range of 0-255 and so on. The current release supports the following standard modes:
>
> 1 (1-bit pixels, black and white, stored with one pixel per byte)
>
> L (8-bit pixels, black and white)
>
> P (8-bit pixels, mapped to any other mode using a color palette)
>
> RGB (3x8-bit pixels, true color)
>
> RGBA (4x8-bit pixels, true color with transparency mask)
>
> CMYK (4x8-bit pixels, color separation)
>
> YCbCr (3x8-bit pixels, color video format)Note that this refers to the JPEG, and not the ITU-R BT.2020, standard
>
> LAB (3x8-bit pixels, the L*a*b color space)
>
> HSV (3x8-bit pixels, Hue, Saturation, Value color space)
>
> I (32-bit signed integer pixels)
>
> F (32-bit floating point pixels)
>
> Pillow also provides limited support for a few additional modes, including:
>
> LA (L with alpha)
>
> PA (P with alpha)
>
> RGBX (true color with padding)
>
> RGBa (true color with premultiplied alpha)
>
> La (L with premultiplied alpha)
>
> I;16 (16-bit unsigned integer pixels)
>
> I;16L (16-bit little endian unsigned integer pixels)
>
> I;16B (16-bit big endian unsigned integer pixels)
>
> I;16N (16-bit native endian unsigned integer pixels)
>
> BGR;15 (15-bit reversed true colour)
>
> BGR;16 (16-bit reversed true colour)
>
> BGR;24 (24-bit reversed true colour)
>
> BGR;32 (32-bit reversed true colour)

Comment: Did you try imagemagick?

Comment: Python Wand which is based upon Imagemagick or use a subprocess call from Python to Imagemgick command line.